# Why does sudo depend on vi?

Tags: linux, vim, fedora, sudo

the package `sudo-1.8.15-2.fc23.x86_64` in fedora 23 depends on vi, as attested by:

`$ rpm -qR sudo | grep vi
/usr/bin/vi`

Why? Is it a mistake on the side of the package maintainer? This dependency causes at least [one bug](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1346332) in fedora 23.

I'm running fedora 23, as attested by:

`uname -a
Linux localhost.localdomain 4.2.3-300.fc23.x86_64 #1 SMP Mon Oct 5 15:42:54 UTC 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux`

Comment: Probably because `visudo` and `sudoedit` *by default* uses vi. I am not sure how the bug report you linked is relevant though, since `vi` != `vim`.

Comment: @TomYan dnf removes sudo when user executes `sudo dnf remove vim-minimal`. That's probably a bug with dnf.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because `visudo` is using `vi` as a default editor.